# Writing a program using While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I want my program that to accept user number input and output the sum from 1 up to the input number (using while loop).
Example: If input value is 4, the sum is 10 i.e., 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.

My code compiles but returns a never ending 1 until my jcreator stops responding.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

    public class SumLoopWhile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number;
    int sum = 1;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    number = in.nextInt();

    while (sum <= 10) {
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
        number++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't alter the value of `sum` at all in your `while` loop. The way you have it now, it's an infinite loop.

Comment: Kindly show me how to do it? @UnknownOctopus

Comment: why are you doing `while (sum <= 10)`? That makes zero sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be comparing the value to the `number` that was input, and adding to the `sum`. Finally, display the result after the loop. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number: ");
    int number = in.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    int v = 0;
    while (v <= number) {
        sum += v;
        v++;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
}
```

Which will print `Sum is: 10` when the input is 4 (as requested).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you want it's to modify the `sum` inside your `while` loop. Do it like this:

```
while (sum <= 10) {
    sum = sum + number;
    number++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
```

You have to put your `System.out.println` out of the loop because you want to print the total value, not each sum that it's calculated in each iteration.

Also, it should be nice that when you want to initialize some `int` that will be a "total" variable (like the result of a sum, rest or whatever), initialize it to zero.

```
int sum = 0;
```

Comment: It's working but when I entered 4, the output should be 10 that is 1+2+3+4 @Error404

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.println` should not be placed inside the `while` loop, because it will get executed as many times as the loop.If you want to print the sum value only once, then the statement `System.out.println` must be placed outside the loop block.

Just use another variable for counting the iterations.For example

```
while(count<=number)
{
    sum=sum+count;
    count++
}
System.out.println("Sum is: "+ sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output variable sum is having the same value throughout the program.it is not getting altered.the while loop becomes infinite loop

The Condition
 (sum <= 10) never becomes true and the while loop will run for infinite times

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SumUsingWhileLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input the number:");
        int number;
        number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        int sum = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= number) {
            sum += i;
            i++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sum = " + sum);
        System.exit(0);
   }

}
```